# React trying to map a value to an SVG so an icon is dynamically rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a React component that returns a `country-code` - I want to build on that so that I can pass that country-code into another component and map through the values, returning the appropiate icon based on the country code. I really am starting from scratch and don't really know how to approach it so any suggestions on best options would be really appreciated.

The value so far is like so:
`key={option.code}` // may output something like "AFN"

```
import Afghanistan from "./CountryFlags/Afghanistan.svg";
import Albania from "./CountryFlags/Albania.svg"

const countryList = [
  {
    countryCode: "AFN",
    name: "afghanistan",
    icon: Afghanistan
  },
  {
    countryCode: "ALL", 
    name: "albania",
    icon: Albania
  },
];

export default countryList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it as a ReactComponent

```
import React, {ReactComponent} from 'react';
import { ReactComponent as Afghanistan } from "./CountryFlags/Afghanistan.svg";
import { ReactComponent as Albania } from "./CountryFlags/Albania.svg"

const countryList = [
  {
    countryCode: "AFN",
    name: "afghanistan",
    icon: </Afghanistan>
  },
  {
    countryCode: "ALL", 
    name: "albania",
    icon: </Albania>
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dead set on having your countries in an array, you could use [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the icon like so: `countryList.find(({countryCode}) => countryCode === "AFN").icon`. Instead of that though, it would make more sense to have the country list be an object that is keyed by countryCode. Like so:

```js
const countryList = {
  AFN: {
    countryCode: "AFN",
    name: "afghanistan",
    icon: Afghanistan
  },
  ALL: {
    countryCode: "ALL", 
    name: "albania",
    icon: Albania
  },
};
```

Then all you have to do is `countryList["AFN"].icon`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code in the component you are using the data to render,

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import countryList from ".."//your data file path

const CountriesListComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(countryList)

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((obj) => {
        <div>
          <p>{obj.countryCode}</p>
          <img src={obj.icon} alt="logo" />
        </div>
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default CountriesListComponent
```